# Can you disable the CTI Inbound call Screen Pop for certain users?

Tags: cti

Is it possible to disable the CTI-based screen pop for inbound calls *for one (or more) specific users*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create and assign (at the profile level) multiple Softphone layouts with different screen pop scenarios.

For profiles that should not have a screen pop, ensure the softphone layout has "Don't pop any screen" for each record matching option in "Screen Pop Settings":
[Designing a Custom Softphone Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cti_admin_phonelayoutscreate.htm&type=5)

Comment: So, just to confirm, this can only be done at the Profile level, and not the specific user level (in a Perm Set, etc)...correct?

Comment: @BobMount that is correct. You'd have to put the specific users in their own profile(s). Or, you might be able to use a flow that closes itself, or navigates back (depending on "Screen pops open within"), using an embeded Aura Lightning component, and checking a custom permission on the current user, otherwise navigate to the matching record(s). But that's more than you asked and probably not a good UX.